# django , requests download file

Tags: python, django, web-applications, python-requests

I am trying to download a file from another server, I want to save it in a local server and create a download link, so that user would be able to download it from our website.

I can download it with requests, it works fine but I don't have idea how to save the file in static files directory  and create a *url* for it. Guide me please

```
import requests
def download_file(url):
   local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
   r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
   with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
return local_filename
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save generated and user uploaded file to `MEDIA_ROOT` folder instead of `STATIC_ROOT`. They will be served at `localhost:8000/media/test.txt` with default settings. 
So you should do something like `return redirect(settings.MEDIA_URL + '/' + local_filename)` in your function.

Check [this](https://timmyomahony.com/blog/static-vs-media-and-root-vs-path-in-django/) blog post for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might use `FileField`. You might create a model for this kind of file with a foreign key to `User`. This field saves the file to your `Storage` and generates an url by calling `url()` method. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#filefield